# O(1) Time complexity solution for finding largest Sibling of a number

Tags: c, complexity-theory

I got one question where i have to find largest siblings from set of digits of a given number. For example, the sibling of 123 are 123, 213, 321, 312, 132, 312, 231. And the largest of them is 321.

This can be done using array as well.

Implementation 1.

1. Extract individual elements and fill same in the array
2. Do Reverse sort.
3. Combine all the elements

Implementation 2.

1. Extract individual elements and fill same in the array
2. First elements in the stack
3. Traverse through the array and push the elements of the array into stack in such a way that the largest element is on top of the stack.

But this also consume O(n) as I need to traverse entire stack.

Any optimum solution is welcome.

Comment: `O(1)` is not possible. You need to read the number, at least. It already takes `O(number of digits)` time.

Comment: @user2040251 So if the number of digits is fixed in advance, it can be O(1). :)

Comment: Do you know what is the type of the number given? Fixed or variable size?

Comment: The number is fixed. For eg. its a function int largest_Sib(int N), and its called from main () -> largest_Sib(1243). It should return 4321. Largest Sibling. i need O(1) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Any solution requires sorting the digits of the number. Comparison sorts are `O(n log n)` where `n` is the number of objects to be sorted, but since digits are a restricted set of elements, you could use a counting sort to achieve `O(n)`.

It should be easy to search the internet (or any basic textbook on algorithm design) for more details, but here are a couple of Wikipedia links to get you started:

- [Comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort)
- [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternative that give performance close to `O(1)`:

When parsing number (extracting decimals or other components), just set bits in the resulting bit mask, which size equals to the base (like 10 in case of decimals).

After all bits are set, you can look for bits set and create output.

While neither part of the algorithm is `O(1)`, in practice, you may consider it to be close to that. Some platforms have assembler instructions, that can help the cause.

Comment: Nice approach, please explain by pseudo code. this part -> " just set bits in the resulting bit mask, which size equals to the base (like 10 in case of decimals).

After all bits are set, you can look for bits set and create output."

Answer (score 1):

If no digits are allowed to repeat, there is an O(1) solution to this, because there is an upper bound on the length of the list.  Why?  Because there are a finite number of digit characters, hence the length of the list is bounded above by the number of digit characters by the pigeon-hole principal.

Note that there is an O(1) solution to this if and only if there is an upper bound to the length of the list.

Proof:
If there is an upper bound on the length of the list, there are a finite number of possible inputs.  Resolving any of the inputs will take a finite amount of time, and the maximum of finitely many finite values will just be a constant.  Different algorithms may change the constant, but assuming you consider only correct algorithms, each algorithm will still complete in an amount of time bounded by some constant.

Conversely, if the time required is O(1), there is an upper bound on how many digits need to be considered.  Since only finitely many digits need consideration, there must be an upper bound on the length of the list since otherwise, you could not determine how many 9s are in the list.

Assuming no upper bound on the length of the list (and therefore, repetitions allowed), your best bet is to count the number of each digit that is required and then to display number listing the digits with their repetitions in descending order.